# Working with object

Tags: c#, object

consider the variable ob4 as shown in figure[image: variable ob4]

now : how can i reach ob4[0]->[0,2]

```
var o=ob4[0];
double[,] p=(double[,]) o[0,0];
```

the line (*double[,] p=(double[,]) o[0,0]*;) gives the following error :
Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'

Comment: Try ob4[0,2] as ob4 is a multidimensional array.

Comment: You should really use some better types than arrays of unknown objects…

Comment: @FizzBuzz: No it's not - it's of type `object[]`. See the screenshot.

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm wondering here why var does not do this cast (object[,])?! if he just remove the var and object[,] o = ob4[0]; this will work or not?

Comment: @BassamAlugili: Why would you expect it to? The compile-time type of `ob4` is `object[]`, so the compile-time type of `ob4[0]` is `object`, not `object[,]`. The code you've suggested wouldn't compile.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to cast `o[0, 0]` to `object[,]` first:

```
var o = (object[,]) ob4[0];
double[,] p = (double[,]) o[0, 0];
```

It would be better if you could avoid having all these nested multi-dimensional arrays with so little type information at compile-time though - you haven't given us much context, but if you could change your object model, it would help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Well, from the error message it is obvious that the runtime thinks `o` is `object`, not `object[,]`. So you might want to change your code to:

```
double[,] = (double[,])((object[,])o)[0,0];
```

Now the runtime knows that `o` should be treated as `object[,]`.